# Display counted records from partial

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, activerecord

I have a ruby application in which I have post and like models. I want to be able to click a like button and then refresh the number of likes for the post. For that I'm using ajax.

My question is how I can count the likes for the post in my partial html document. At the moment the code in my _show.html.erb looks like this:

```
<%= @post.likes.all.count %>
```

The div in which I would like to show the code in the index.html.erb looks like this:

```
<div>
        Likes: <div id="<% post.id %>_likes_output", local: :post></div>
</div>
```

And my create.js.erb looks like this:

```
$(document.getElementById("<%@post%> _likes_output").innerHTML = "<%= render partial: "likes/show", local: :post %>");
```

My Like create method looks like this:

```
def create
  @user = current_user.id
  @post = params[:post_id]
  likes = {user_id: @user, post_id: @post}
  @like = Like.new(likes)

  # a new entry in the likes table gets created
  if @like.save!
  else
    flash[:alert] = "Something went wrong"
  end
end
```

At the moment I'm getting the following error:

```
Started POST "/posts/13/likes" for ::1 at 2019-03-22 11:38:28 +0100
Processing by LikesController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"post_id"=>"13"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/likes_controller.rb:4
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/likes_controller.rb:10
  Post Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 13], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/likes_controller.rb:10
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/likes_controller.rb:10
  Like Create (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "likes" ("created_at", "updated_at", "user_id", "post_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", "2019-03-22 10:38:28.067946"], ["updated_at", "2019-03-22 10:38:28.067946"], ["user_id", "1"], ["post_id", "13"]]
  ↳ app/controllers/likes_controller.rb:10
   (1.0ms)  commit transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/likes_controller.rb:10
  Rendering likes/create.js.erb
  Rendered likes/_show.html.erb (21.0ms)
  Rendered likes/create.js.erb (38.8ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 91ms (ActiveRecord: 1.8ms)



ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `likes' for "13":String
Did you mean?  lines):
    1: <%= @post.likes.all.count %>

app/views/likes/_show.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_likes__show_html_erb___2777362880017156755_70224479796840'
app/views/likes/create.js.erb:3:in `_app_views_likes_create_js_erb__712898782247662482_70224408518740'
```

Please let me know if there is something else you need. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@flo3719 there may be other issues reside in your code but the issue you mentioned `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method 'likes' for "13":String` is due to the culprit line `@post = params[:post_id]`, due to this line your `@post` object contains `"13"` in the view.

You should find your post from the database by using:

```
@post = Post.find_by_id(params[:post_id])
```

Replace your `@post = params[:post_id]` with below code

`@post = Post.find_by_id(params[:post_id])`

Comment: That worked great, thank you. Now I'm getting the error ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: Post must exist):
app/controllers/likes_controller.rb:10:in `create' 
Do you have any idea WHAT THE PROBLEM NOW IS?

Comment: @flo3719 I think there is an association of post with likes for example post has many likes or post has one like. You are creating a like with a post but the post does not exist in the database. 
Here on this line `likes = {user_id: @user, post_id: @post}` please check your `@post` object; it must be present in the database.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your `@post` is a string. Here

```
@post = params[:post_id]
```

should be

```
@post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
```

Answer (score 0):

You should find your post instead of passing id:

```
@post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
```

Also, consider using counter_cache for storing the number of likes - much better in terms of performance! https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-belongs-to-counter-cache